# How to keep union type inside other type instead of destructure it

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```js
type Test = {
  checked: boolean;
  selection: 'female' | 'male'
}
```

And, I would like to transform it into another type such as:

```js
type Test = {
  checked: Record<string, boolean>;
  selection: Record<string, 'female' | 'male'>
}
```

Then, I wrote this transform:

```js
type NestedTest<T> = T extends object
  ? { [P in keyof T]: NestedTest<T[P]> }
  : Record<string, T>;
```

But, when I call it like:

```js
type Test2 = NestedTest<Test>;
```

Then I got the unexpected results below:

```js
type Test2 = {
    checked: Record<string, false> | Record<string, true>;
    selection: Record<string, "female"> | Record<string, "male">;
}
```

As you can see, typescript auto splits these union types into a union of `Record` type instead of only one.

I don't why it is like that. If you can, please tell me what I misunderstood? and how to fix it.

Here is my [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8CwAoKUDGAFhHgNYQAmAXFAEYD2dANhAIYB2A3NrvBM3sACWdNtQDkAMwgBbFszFQAPlDGz52AL7ZsoSFAByCYBTiIAPDAB8KWFAgAPY23LwodGgCtiwblAD86FAA2gAKUIJsUGQgdBKwALrUhogmRhah8dZaOFDUAErEdABO5GaIRREA5gA0sJZcWDrg0KbAAEw2ycbkrRZG9dpYAPRDdvaQAhTYI1C6LUYdqJjDo7i4hMRkVFAFeMWl5VW19EysbAMrazx83sKiO4UlZcAVbDVQAERSahAfSp8-D4XGYaIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to stop the unions from distributing to seperate `Record`s. See [Distributive Conditional Types](https://Distributive%20Conditional%20Types) in the TypeScript docs.

```
type NestedTest<T> = [T] extends [object]
  ? { [P in keyof T]: NestedTest<T[P]> }
  : Record<string, T>;
```

If we surround `T` and `object` with square brackets, the elements of the union will not be distributed to different Records.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=11&ssc=23&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8CwAoKUDGAFhHgNYQAmAXFAEYD2dANhAIYB2A3NrvBM3sACWdNtQDkAMwgBbFszFQAPlDGz5AGm5Q2CYBWqYcuKC2r0mrNloC%202W1myhIUAHK6KcRAB4YAPhRQANowALpQEAAeemzk8EF0NABWxMAhWgD86EEAClCCbFBkIHQSsCHUbogeuj6B2SH%209rjUAErEdABO5F6IHfkA5uqwvlwOWE7QnsAATAGVeuRTProj2NgA9OvhEZACFBtbE7C6s6iGm8a4hMRkVFBteJ3dvQND5szsq1gXl7z8QiJWu0uj1gH02IMoAAiKRqCBQpTQuFQr4XaxAA)